# How can I avoid to return HTML markup for access denied?

Tags: 8, routes, page-controller

I've developed a custom controller that serves as a simple endpoint, POST method.

This controller has custom access control.

Custom access is done by looking for a header in the HTTP request, by making the controller object a service as well.

Everything works great. Except that when I return AccessResult::forbidden() .. I get the HTML of the access denied page .. and I don't really want that .. I'd like to return just a short bit of JSON.

What can I do to return something that is JSON, and not the Access Denied page HTML, for this particular route, when the access() method returns AccessResult::forbidden() ?

I've read that appending ?_format=json to the url works, and in my case it does. Is there anyway to achieve the same result without adding this url parameter?

Comment: You mean like [CSRF access checking](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/csrf-access-checking)?

Comment: I would check what the JSON:API module does, since it outputs JSON instead of HTML markup.

Comment: Actually, Drupal core itself, not a core module, has the class that outputs as JSON a 4xx error like the 403 error caused from `AccessResult::forbidden()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you look into [ParagraphAccessControlHandler](http://api.md-systems.ch/api/paragraphs/paragraphs%21src%21ParagraphAccessControlHandler.php/8.x-1.x) you will find something similar.
Implement something similar in your Access callback.

```
protected function checkCreateAccess(AccountInterface $account, array $context, $entity_bundle = NULL) {



// Allow paragraph entities to be created in the context of entity forms.
  if (\Drupal::requestStack()
    ->getCurrentRequest()
    ->getRequestFormat() === 'html') {
    return AccessResult::allowed()
      ->addCacheContexts([
      'request_format',
    ]);
  }
  return AccessResult::neutral()
    ->addCacheContexts([
    'request_format',
  ]);
}
```